# OpenProject webhooks not fired

Tags: openproject

I'm trying to use the [OpenProject's webhook](https://github.com/opf/openproject-webhooks) to send workpackage's data to a third-party system, but it isn't even fired.

I did all my tests using this [OP docker container](https://store.docker.com/community/images/openproject/community) from version *7.4.0* to *7.4.7* but none of them worked. In all of these images, the webhook is included and configured, then theoretically any additional setting isn't needed (except the webhook register in the web interface).

The *passenger* and the *worker:jobs* are running. There isn't clue in the log files. The webhook is enabled and set to trigger a http POST call in a localhost address.

Did anyone pass through a similar issue? I'm not a Ruby developer, and I wonder if some kind of daemon or service start is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team figured out how to make the webhooks works. It's only needed check the *Work package added* and *Work package updated* options in the *Email notifications* group on *System settings* of the instance.

This is a undocumented setting, and I see it as a feature issue.
Nevertheless, it's working.